# password_hash convert into simple md5 format

Tags: magento-1.9, database, importexport, customer-csv

How to export all customers in simple username , email, and simple md5 format csv.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Dashboard -> system -> import/export -> Dataflow-profiles ->export customers
```

Here you will find Export: drop down under Data formate, You have to select Only **Mapped fields**

Then

```
save and continue -> go for Run profile tab -> Run profile in popup
```

after executeion you will find CSV in /var/export/

Comment: I need password in simple md5 format not in hash and salt add mode.

Comment: Magento creating password in this manner :md5(salt.password):salt.
As per me i didn't use any method to remove salt from MD5 password

Comment: I want all customer record in different database so I need in simple md5 format.

Comment: You can go with this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772665/magento-password-hash-in-customer-info

Comment: Then, md5($salt.$passwordEntered) is equal to $firstPart

Comment: I have a question, I know my password but other customers password I don't know so How can I identify other customers password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50719/discussion-between-ram-sipl-and-chirayu-vyas).